# How to bind textbox to the datable and make it search like google for some field of datable?

Tags: asp.net

i have a populated datatable and a search textbox, 
i want to bind datatable to the search text box and
want to make it search like google, how can i achive this?

Edited :
Like i want my search box to start searching all the first name which are similar when i start typing characters it starts searching for similar records as i type more character it display below more correct record like google

Comment: @NTDN - I'm afraid your question isn't too clear. What do you mean by 'search like google'? Are you wanting to search the contents of your DataTable? Are you wanting some sort of autocomplete?

Comment: Like i want my search box to start searching all the first name which are similar when i start typing characters it starts searching for similar records as i type more character it display below more correct record like google.

Comment: @Andy Rose: Not like autocomplete, autocomplete is different because it searches for all  records which are searched in the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you ask is called **AutoComplete**

You can search on Internet for more example, there are on jQuery, on asp.net Ajax control Toolkit, on Yahoo UI, and stand alone.

The asp.net ajax
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

Some on jQuery
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

The yahoo ui
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/